# How do I write python code that handles URLError Exception for both py2 and py3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exception

I read about `urllib.error.URLError`exception. I found that it is no longer available on python2.x. And I have the following code that I want to make it py2 and py3 compatible. How can I do this?

```
 try:
    if "api_key" not in app_data:
        app_data["api_key"] = None
    userprofile = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow, app_key=app_data["api_key"]).user(userid)
    print(bold("\n User: " + userprofile.display_name.format()))
    print("\n\tReputations: " + userprofile.reputation.format())
    print_warning("\n\tBadges:")
    print("\t\t   Gold: " + str(userprofile.gold_badges))
    print("\t\t Silver: " + str(userprofile.silver_badges))
    print("\t\t Bronze: " + str(userprofile.bronze_badges))
    print("\t\t  Total: " + str(userprofile.badge_total))
    print_warning("\n\tStats:")
    total_questions = len(userprofile.questions.fetch())
    unaccepted_questions = len(userprofile.unaccepted_questions.fetch())
    accepted = total_questions - unaccepted_questions
    rate = accepted / float(total_questions) * 100
    print("\t\t Total Questions Asked: " + str(len(userprofile.questions.fetch())))
    print('\t\t        Accept rate is: %.2f%%.' % rate)
    #check if the user have answers and questions or no. 
    if userprofile.top_answer_tags.fetch():
        print('\nMost experienced on %s.' % userprofile.top_answer_tags.fetch()[0].tag_name)
    else:
        print("You have 0 answers")
    if userprofile.top_question_tags.fetch():
        print('Most curious about %s.' % userprofile.top_question_tags.fetch()[0].tag_name)
    else:
        print("You have 0 questions")
except urllib.error.URLError:
    print_fail("Please check your internet connectivity...")
    exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    showerror(e)
    if str(e) == "400 [bad_parameter]: `key` doesn't match a known application":
        print_warning("Wrong API key... Deleting the data file...")
        del_datafile()
        exit(1)
    elif str(e) in ("not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)", "400 [bad_parameter]: ids"):
        global manual
        if manual == 1:
            print_warning("Wrong user ID specified...")
            helpman()
            exit(1)
        print_warning("Wrong user ID... Deleting the data file...")
        del_datafile()
        exit(1)
```

Comment: If you can use install packages, you might want to look at [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves.urllib.error), the linked part in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `six` lib, as @Kendas suggests in the comments:

```
from six.moves import urllib
```

Or you could try to import `URLError` and catch `ImportError` exceptions:

```
try : 
    from urllib.error import URLError
except ImportError: 
    from urllib2 import URLError
```

If you choose the second option you'll have to apply the same metod to other modules, such as `urlopen`, etc.

Comment: The second solution works well for me; thank you so much.